# How can I convert Css to React-native

Tags: css, react-native

I want to do the exact same thing of what this CSS styling suggests in react native

So how can I convert this CSS to React -native

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

.grid-item {
  flex-grow: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: 33%;
}

.grid-item:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3n+0) {
  border-right: none;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 400px;
}

.list-item {
  flex-grow: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  flex: 1;
}

.list-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">

  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">
    
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to make a Modal  which looks like this:

```
       <Modal>
          <BrandsGrid />
       </Modal>
       <Modal>
          <ModelsList />
       </Modal>
```

I need to define BrandsGrid and ModelsList and do something exactly similar to that CSS styling in React-native

So example codes will be more helpful for understanding I have referred the docs but couldn't get much help from that

Answer (score 0):

You can use different modules for converting css components to react native. For example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-react-native-transform

Another great example:

https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-css-transformer

Comment: It's better you add code as part of your answer along with the references.